# How to change params to prevent xgboost accuracy get stuck

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying to train a xgboost model using `multi:softmax` objective, but accuracy score gets stuck.

Code:

```
#preparing dataset omitted
xgb_params = {
    "objective": "multi:softmax",
    "eta": 1,
    "num_class": 62,
    "max_depth": 10,
    "nthread": 4,
    "eval_metric": "merror",
    "print.every.n": 1,
    "silent": 1,
    "early.stop.round": 5
}
num_rounds = 5

mask = np.random.choice([False, True], len(X_train), p=[0.5, 0.5])
not_mask = [not i for i in mask]

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train[not_mask], label=y[not_mask])
dtrain_watch = xgb.DMatrix(X_train[mask], label=y[mask])
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test)
watchlist = [(dtrain_watch, 'eval')]

gbdt = xgb.train(xgb_params, dtrain, num_rounds, watchlist)
preds = gbdt.predict(dtest)
```

Output:

```
[0] eval-merror:0.989950
[1] eval-merror:0.989950
[2] eval-merror:0.989950
[3] eval-merror:0.989950
[4] eval-merror:0.989950
```

What parameters I need to change to reflect any change eval-merror in iterations?

EDIT: I have tried to change eta to 0.01, 0.1, 0.3 and 1 but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not about parameters, it's about your data.

You can test it by taking a different data set (from kaggle for example) and build a model just like this, but probably with a different `"num_class": x`, according to the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could carry out parameter tuning using sklearn [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). But if you don't have time just increase `early.stop.round` and `max_depth` and lower `eta`